# Three.js: Plane visible only half the time

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a plane, which I rotate, using Three.js. For some reason, the plane doesn't show half the time. I've created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/5/) showing the behaviour.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Note that this has changed slightly in Three.js revision r50. Rendering both sides of a plane can be achieved through the `side` property on the Material, i.e.

```
plane.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Look [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) for more details.

Comment: do you know how to get 2 different textures on the 2 sides? Anyone?

Comment: @mattdlockyer I had the same question and this helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709760/how-can-i-put-two-different-textures-on-the-front-and-back-of-a-plane

Answer (score 18):

It's not visible because the backface of the plane does not get rendered (or better said, a plane doesn't have backfaces per default. On a side note, have a look at [backface-culling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) regarding this. Although it's not the issue in this case, it may give you a little insight about rendering).

Three.js does give you a very easy way to render backfaces though.

In Three.js - **r49 and below**:

All you need to do is set the `doubleSided` - property of your plane-Object to true.

```
plane.doubleSided = true;
```

For newer versions - **r50 and up**

In newer revisions, as donnyB already stated correctly in his answer, the property was moved from the `Object3D` - object to the `Material` - object, so you'd need to set it a little differently, like so:

```
plane.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

Also edited your fiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/1084/

it is using a Three.js - version newer than r50, the property is set on line 35

Comment: great job, didn't know your solution was for those revisions, good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @mattdlockyer perhaps you should remove the downvote now if it's yours.