# How can I put two different textures on the front and back of a plane?

Tags: javascript, textures, three.js

PRoblem: i'm trying to create (just for fun) a simple poker card (with a card back and a card front).
I have two different images, for back and front.
I easily created a Plane geometry with a single texture for both sides, but i really don't know how to assign a texture for a side and the other texture for the other side...
i tried this (without success :( ):

```
var textureBack = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/cardBack.png' );
var textureFront = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/cardFront.png' );      

var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureBack } );
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureFront } );

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 90, 110, 1, 1 );            
geometry.faces[ 0 ].materials.push( material1 );
geometry.faces[ 1 ].materials.push( material2 );

var card = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());
```

any help, please? :)

Comment: A somewhat leaner solution below, took a long time so I thought I would share!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place two plane geometries back-to-back.

First, create a geometry for the front.

```
var geometry1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 90, 110, 1, 1 );
```

Now create another geometry for the back.

```
var geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 90, 110, 1, 1 );
```

Spin it 180 degrees.

```
geometry2.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY( Math.PI ) );
```

After you load the materials, create the meshes, and add them as children of a "card" object.

```
// textures
var textureFront = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/cardFront.png' );      
var textureBack = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/cardBack.png' );

// material
var material1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: textureFront } );
var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, map: textureBack } );

// card
card = new THREE.Object3D();
scene.add( card );

// mesh
mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material1 );
card.add( mesh1 );
mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material2 );
card.add( mesh2 );
```

You'll have an easier time with this if you use `WebGLRenderer`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdAb7/11/

Updated to three.js r.69

Comment: Ok! i've tried the first solution, and it worked!!!! many many thanks :)

one point (maybe can avoid waste time for someone...): the piece of code

    "geometry1.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI / 2 ) );"

don't function, because the method name to make a rotation, although in the documentation is 'makeRotationX', is 'setRotationX' :D

Now i'll try the second solution, too ;)

Comment: I tried the second solution, and it works, too... but i see that with the second solution all animations are slow... 
Anyway, thank you again! problem resolved :D

Comment: `setRotationX` is from an old version of the library. You need to update to r.49.

Comment: Ops: i really was convinced i have the right version oO i'll update ;) PS: sorry but... how  can i accept this answer? EDIT: ok ok i've just done it! ;)

Comment: Hey guys, see my answer below to save some extra memory / geometry calls, updates or whatever

Comment: @WestLangley May I critise your jsfiddle sample? the CSS side is bad, there is no need to use `overflow` property, just set body && html => width/height: 100% and margin/padding: 0. And as for canvas set `display: block;`, you could see the my sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/xBLYa/ (I'm doing it in JS via setCssStyle() function, but you can set it into a signle CSS file or into <style> tag in <head>)

Comment: @WestLangley yea, there are many ways, but correct one - not so many, why do you need overflow, what are you trying to overflow with CSS?

Comment: @GeloVolro This post is about texturing a plane using three.js. If you have a CSS question, please make a new post.

Comment: @WestLangley I just to make your answer much more pretty :)

Answer (score 12):

Was searching for solution without duplicating all my geometry.

Here you go ladies and gentlemen...

```
var materials = [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, side: THREE.FrontSide}),
                 new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureBack, side: THREE.BackSide})];

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height);

for (var i = 0, len = geometry.faces.length; i < len; i++) {
    var face = geometry.faces[i].clone();
    face.materialIndex = 1;
    geometry.faces.push(face);
    geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push(geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i].slice(0));
}

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)));
```

BOOM a Two Faced Plane for ya, the loop will also work with geometries with more faces, replicating each face and applying the BackSide texture to it.

Enjoy!

Comment: could you please help me flip the texture? there is a mirror effect

Comment: You have to go through the UVs and flip them. Make your geometry object a global variable temporarily and then run your app. In Chrome use the javascript console and type the variable name of the geometry object (now global) and traverse it's contents. You should see the texture UV coordinates stored there, flip their order in the way you'd like to see your texture appear.

Comment: This is good for a dynamic geometry object (e.g. a flapping plane) as you only have to update 1 geometry.  The mirroring problem can be avoided by using this solution with a mirrored image file as input for the back side of the plane.  But for a simple flag e.g. Stars & Stripes just using "DoubleSide" works fine.

Comment: how to make it work with gltf