# Use different textures for front/back faces of a Three.js DoubleSide material

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is it possible to specify two different textures for a THREE.DoubleSide material?

Currently I am doing this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
```

Which will use the same texture for both front/back faces.

I would like to use a different texture for each face.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709760/how-can-i-put-two-different-textures-on-the-front-and-back-of-a-plane

Comment: @WestLangley the solution described there is deprecated.

THREE.GeometryUtils: .merge() has been moved to Geometry. Use geometry.merge( geometry2, matrix, materialIndexOffset ) instead.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the solution that used that technique -- though for a different reason.