# How apply different materials to either sides of a plane in three.js?

Tags: three.js

I have created the simple triangle plane using

```
materials = [];
material1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff00ff, specular: 0xff00ff, shininess: -3, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.FrontSide } );
material2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xf0f0ff, specular: 0xf0f0ff, shininess: -3, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.BackSide } );
materials.push(material1);
materials.push(material2);
mat = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials);

tri = new THREE.Geometry();
tri.vertices.push(1, 1 ,1);
tri.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0,1,2));
tri = new THREE.Mesh(tri, mat);

scene.add(tri);
```

I am not able to get different materials to be applied on either side. How can I do it ?

I am trying to acheive this kind of effect
[image]

Comment: what is `f[i]` in your code? It should be `mesh = new THREE.Mesh(tri, mat); scene.add(mesh)`

Comment: I edited it. its tri now

Comment: plane and sides? how does that work? What kind of a mesh are you creating with this code? Looks like a single vertex and one face, not sure how that works? Screenshot?

Comment: When we create a plane they have 2 sides correct ? Normal and Anti-normal. If I flip the plane it should have a different color than the former side of the plane.

Comment: I found this post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709760/how-can-i-put-two-different-textures-on-the-front-and-back-of-a-plane
But that is not exactly the solution but the effect is as desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
var face = tri.faces[0].clone();
face.materialIndex = 1;
tri.faces.push(face);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j8k7yhLp/1/

Comment: That worked perfectly well... But Is there way to create it without cloning the polygons ?

Comment: When we create a plane they have only one side.