# Faces does not have backs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have that code:

```
var roofGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

roofGeometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0, 0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, 0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(0.5, 0, -0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, -0.5),
    new THREE.Vector3(-0.5, 0, -0.5)
);
roofGeometry.faces.push(
    new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2),
    //new THREE.Face4(1, 3, 4, 2),
    new THREE.Face3(5, 3, 4)/*,
    new THREE.Face4(0, 5, 4, 2)*/
);
//...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jFyFJ

Why the triangles are disappering when I rotate them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889583/three-js-plane-visible-only-half-the-time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `side: THREE.DoubleSide` in material

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFyFJ/2/)